# Почему происходит deadlock?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Изучаю потоки в java. Хотел бы создать программу, которая бескочно симмулировала счет игры Спартак - Динамо. Однако, почему-то программа лочится. Логика такая: имеется синхронизироанное свойство score. Если счет более двух очков в пользу Спартака, тогда этот поток уходит в ожидание. Также и для Динамо. Когда счет обнуляется происхоидт извещение потока. Но происхоидит ситуация вроде такой Спартак 1 2, затем Динамо 1 0 -1 -2 и программа уходит в dead lock не завершаясь. Не могли вы подсказать почему так происходит и как лучше переделать?

```
public class WaitNotify {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Score sc = new Score();
    Spartak s = new Spartak(sc);
    Dinamo d = new Dinamo(sc);

    s.start();
    d.start();  
}
}

class Spartak extends Thread {
Score score;
public Spartak(Score s) {
    score = s;  
}   
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        if (score.getScore() < 2) {
            score.plus();
            System.out.println("Spartak " + score.getScore());
            if (score.getScore() > 0) {
                synchronized (score) {
                    score.notify();
                }

            }

        } else {
            synchronized (score) {
                    try {
                         score.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            };
        }

    }
}   
}

class Dinamo extends Thread {
Score score;
public Dinamo(Score s) {
    score = s;  
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {

        if (score.getScore() > -2) {
            score.minus();
            System.out.println("Dinamo " + score.getScore());
            if (score.getScore() < 0) {
                synchronized (score) {
                    score.notify();
                }

            }

        } else {
            synchronized (score) {
                try {
                     score.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            };

        }

    }
}   
}

class Score {
private int score;

public Score() {
    score = 0;
}

public Score(int sc) {
    score = sc;
}

public synchronized void plus() {
    score++;
}

public synchronized void minus() {
    score--;
}

public int getScore(){
    return score;
}

}
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что у вас именно deadlock? Может, у вас livelock — программа крутится бесконечно? Попробуйте отладочную печать, выясните, в каких точках какие потоки блокированы.

И да, если у вас score разделён между потоками, синхронизировать необходимо _все_ операции с ним, а не только wait/notify.

Comment: да программа крутиться бесконечно. мне здесь подсказали (ответ почему-то удалили), что возможно создаются два разных экземпляра класса score и оба из них уходят в wait. я постарался сделать singlton, но резултат остался прежним

Comment: @cadmy ответ я удалил, т.к. ошибся с разными экземплярами Score. У вас точно livelock. Синглетон вам ни к чему.

Comment: а как его избежать?

Comment: @cadmy: Ну, попробуйте сформулировать, что вы хотите от программы. Когда она должна остановиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идея в общем верна, но неверно взаимодействие с разделяемым состоянием.

Вы допускаете типичную ошибку, сначала сравниваете shared state с каким-то значением, и только потом в критической секции выполняете логику. К моменту выполнения кода в критической секции, проверяемое вами условие уже может быть нарушено. Таким образом ваша попытка держать значение счета в интервале -2;2 вероятно проваливается.

Дополнительно вы допускаете еще одну ошибку, т.к. метод getScore() не синхронизирован, то он может вернуть некорректное значение.

Добавть логирование в обе ветки else, чтобы видеть, когда поток переходит в состояние wait. В момент, когда ваша программа зависает (как вам кажется) сделайте thread dump, и посмотрите чем занимаются потоки.